# Apache: why always showing files from the same virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, documentroot

I have set up 2 virtual hosts, sharing the same IP address:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs"
        ServerName www.website1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/website2.com/httpdocs"
        ServerName www.website2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If I type www.website2.com, the files shown are always by www.website1.com

I am correctly restarting Apache after each change.

I can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Why do you say you are "correctly restarting Apache"? Exactly how are you doing that? Why do you believe it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

The `VirtualHost` directive should match the `NameVirtualHost` value.

In my case, I am just setting up a simple `http`, so it's `*:80`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs"
        ServerName www.website1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/website2.com/httpdocs"
        ServerName www.website2.com
</VirtualHost>
```